# Make PowerShell think an object is not enumerable

Tags: powershell

I've been working on some PowerShell functions to manage objects implemented in an assembly we have created.  One of the classes I have been working with implements IEnumerable.  Unfortunatly, this causes PowerShell to unroll the object at every opportunity.  (I can't change the fact that the class implements IEnumerable.)

I've worked around the problem by creating a PSObject and copying the properties of our custom object to the PSObject, then returning that instead of the custom object.  But I'd really rather return our custom object.

Is there some way, presumably using my types.ps1xml file, to hide the GetEnumerator() method of this class from PowerShell (or otherwise tell PowerShell to never unroll it).

Comment: So you have a custom collection class and you dont want powershell to treat it as a collection ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. The class has things on it other than the collection.  Please don't let this devolve into a discussion on the (de)merits of whether or not this class should be enumerable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrapping in a [`PSObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject(VS.85).aspx) is probably the best way.

You could also explicitly wrap it in another collection—PowerShell only unwraps one level.

Also when writing a cmdlet in C#/VB/... when you call [`WriteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568370(VS.85).aspx) use the overload that takes a second parameter: if false then PowerShell will not enumerate the object passed as the first parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the Write-Output replacement http://poshcode.org/2300 which has a -AsCollection parameter that lets you avoid unrolling. But basically, if you're writing a function that outputs a collection, and you don't want that collection unrolled, you need to use CmdletBinding and PSCmdlet:

```
function Get-Array {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param([Switch]$AsCollection) 

    [String[]]$data = "one","two","three","four"
    if($AsCollection) {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($data,$false)
    } else {
        Write-Output $data
    }
}
```

If you call that with -AsCollection you'll get very different results, although they'll LOOK THE SAME in the console.

```
C:\PS> Get-Array 

one
two
three
four

C:\PS> Get-Array -AsCollection

one
two
three
four

C:\PS> Get-Array -AsCollection| % { $_.GetType() }


IsPublic IsSerial Name       BaseType                             
-------- -------- ----       --------                             
True     True     String[]   System.Array                         



C:\PS> Get-Array | % { $_.GetType() }


IsPublic IsSerial Name       BaseType                             
-------- -------- ----       --------                             
True     True     String     System.Object                        
True     True     String     System.Object                        
True     True     String     System.Object                        
True     True     String     System.Object
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to avoid having it unrolled EVER.  I can return the object from my function without unrolling it by using the return-as-array trick (or what you describe).  But eventually I'll end up unrolling it by accident.

Comment: Simply put: I know of no way to do that, but please don't try :) ... If you DO find a way you'll just end up causing a bunch of bug reports from people unable to figure out why your collection doesn't have anything in it even though .Count reports a nice big number.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly answer the original question, since it technically isn't returning the custom object itself, but I had a similar problem where I was trying to display the properties of a custom type that implements `IEnumerable` and thought it was worth sharing. Piping this object into cmdlets like `Get-Member` and `Select-Object` always enumerates the contents of the collection. However, using those cmdlets directly and passing the object to the `-InputObject` parameter produces the expected results. Here, I'm using an `ArrayList` as an example, but `$list` can be an instance of your custom collection type:

```
# Get a reference to a collection instance
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(1,2,3)

# Display the properties of the collection (in this case, the ArrayList),
# not the items it contains (Int32)
Select-Object -InputObject $list -Property *

# List the members of the ArrayList class, not the contained items
Get-Member -InputObject $list
```

As other comments have mentioned, you can save the results of `Select-Object` as a variable, creating a new `PSObject` that you can use directly without enumerating the contents:

```
# Wrap the collection in a PSObject
$obj = Select-Object -InputObject $list -Property *

# Properties are displayed without enumerating contents
$obj
$obj | Format-List
$obj | Format-Table
```